# restoring aurora cluster from s3 or restoring from snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, database-backups, amazon-aurora

well I have couple of questions. I have a aurora cluster with a single MySQL RDS instance which has 450GB of data. we use this cluster only when we are doing some specific testing.so I want to delete this cluster but keep its data available to me so I can make a new cluster whenever we need any testing to be done.
there are couple of ways this can be done as far as I know

1. take a snapshot of the cluster and restore the cluster from the
       snapshot whenever required.
2. backup the cluster to s3 and restore the
       cluster from s3 when required

which way is more faster and which one is more cost efficient?

can an entire cluster be restored from s3 if so what are the steps involved ? , I found the aws documentation bit too messy.

If we stop a aurora cluster, it again automatically restarts within 7 days , is there a way to prevent this automatic restart and keep it stopped when it is not required and start when required ?